# No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I am currently working on cloud technology. In one of my current projects, I created the service fabric cluster in Azure. Then I tried to connect to the cluster through Windows PowerShell. I got the error

> No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.

[image: Error message]

Please tell me how to resolve the above issue.

Regards,

Pradeep

Comment: did you a find a solution to this problem?

Comment: yes, what I did mistake for connecting secure cluster using PowerShell before I write the above command I forget to enable the PowerShell script execution.

After known the solution next I was enabled the power shell script execution using this below command.
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser.

For that I was followed the below links.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-portal/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After did a lot of research, I find out the solution for my above problem using these below links.

**Prepare your development environment**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started

**Create a Service Fabric cluster in Azure using the Azure portal**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-portal

What I did mistake for connecting secure cluster using PowerShell is before I write the above command I forget to enable the PowerShell script execution.

So, first I was enabled the power shell script execution using this below command.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```

After that  I used the below command for connecting to my secure cluster, Now  it's working fine.

```
Connect-serviceFabricCluster
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I am trying to deploy from octopus. Should I run these scripts at octopus

Answer (score 2):

I spent a day to figure it out what's wrong. After upgrading or installing from scratch, I faced this problem too!

Slightly change this file  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\NonSecure\OneNode\ClusterManifestTemplate.json with the following items:

- If you try to debug on your localhost, change `iPAddress` to `localhost`

  {
    "name": "DevCluster",
    "clusterConfigurationVersion": "1.0.0",
    "apiVersion": "10-2017",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "nodeName": "_Node_0",
        "iPAddress": "localhost",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/0",
        "upgradeDomain": "0"
      }
    ],
  }
- Add the following parameter to the Hosting section:-

  "name": "Hosting",
  "parameters": [
       ....
    {
      "name": "FabricContainerAppsEnabled",
      "value": "false"
    }
  ]

Answer (score 1):

> `No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue`

### Situation 1:

I got the above error while trying to deploy to Azure. When I tried deploying from Visual Studio, the Connection Endpoint failed to resolve:

[image: Connection Endpoint failed to resolve]

Solution 1:

Turns out I had to open the port (19000) in Azure first!

See [Tutorial: Filter network traffic with a network security group using the Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-filter-network-traffic) for details.

### Situation 2:

Before trying to deploy a second application, I had stopped my local cluster!

Solution 2:

I restarted my local cluster from the tray menu. A related solution is to reset and restart the local cluster.

[image: Local cluster tray menu]

Answer (score 1):

I got this error earlier this week, and after spending a couple hours and working with Microsoft we found that I was using $connections istead of @connections.

```
$connections = @{ ConnectionEndpoint='something.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000'; X509Credential=$true; ServerCertThumbprint='4DC09A1212617326E2080EFE7E1022C6554AAEB9'; FindType='FindByThumbprint'; FindValue='71e5d31e7cbb0d10edb9c62e4d1be6e19de22eae'; StoreLocation='CurrentUser'; StoreName='My' }
# Incorrect:
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster $connections
# Correct:
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @connections
```

Notice that the variable that you pass to Connect-ServiceFabricCluster cmdlet is supposed to be @connections.