# Azure fabric setup issues

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am a fairly new to Azure services. I am trying to install azure fabric and run it locally on my dev machine. 
I created an application using the templates provided in VS 2017. I get the following error when I tried installing fabric and running it.

Tried this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409153/no-cluster-endpoint-is-reachable-please-check-if-there-is-connectivity-firewall) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a74bf0f7-3106-4b48-b48f-4ea250a24964/cluster-setup-errors-connectservicefabriccluster-a-communication-error-caused-the-operation-to?forum=AzureServiceFabric) and still unable to get it to work.

Please can someone help?

Using Cluster Data Root: C:\SfDevCluster\Data
Using Cluster Log Root: C:\SfDevCluster\Log

The generated json path is C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEE68.tmp.json
Processing and validating cluster config.
Create node configuration succeeded
Starting service FabricHostSvc. This may take a few minutes...

Waiting for Service Fabric Cluster to be ready. This may take a few minutes...
Local Cluster ready status: 4% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 8% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 12% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 17% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 21% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 25% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 29% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 33% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 38% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 42% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 46% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 50% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 54% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 58% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 62% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 67% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 71% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 75% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 79% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 83% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 88% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 92% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 96% completed.
Local Cluster ready status: 100% completed.
WARNING: Service Fabric Cluster is taking longer than expected to connect.

Waiting for Naming Service to be ready. This may take a few minutes...
No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS
issue.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:620 char:12
+     [void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @connParams)
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster

Comment: Do you have a local firewall that could be preventing communication?

Comment: @KnowHoper I had disabled firewall. So Firewall cannot be the issue i think

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue on two machines and found a workaround [here](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1056).

It involves adding FabricContainerAppsEnabled to the cluster manifest. Note that we had to re-boot our machines to get the local cluster manager to honor the new setting, though I suppose a service re-start might have worked also.